# R create a unique key from a set of string data

Tags: r

Is there a quick algorithm/function to convert a string into an integer in R

I have a dataframe looks like

```
id_1 id_2 id_3 date        value
1     2    3   2012-11-18   50
1     1    4   2012-05-07   100
```

and

`strtoi(paste(df[,1],df[,3],df[,4],sep='_')` gives me a `NA`

Trying to set up a unique primary key I can use to do some basic arithmetic

Thanks

Comment: Could you not use (and I am assuming that your dataframe is called `mydf`) something like `mydf$KEY <- seq_len(nrow(mydf))`. This is guaranteed to give you a sequence of numeric integers starting at one (if there are any rows in your dataframe) and ending at whatever the number of rows in your database are?

Comment: thanks @SimonO101 I need them to refer accurately to the same text sequence even if they are in a different order in a different data frame so digest works better for me here.

Comment: Great. Well I am glad you got some good solutions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `digest` package

```
library(digest)
temp <- data.frame(x1=c(1:5,1),x2=c(2:6,2),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
temp <- data.frame(temp, uid = apply(temp, 1, digest),stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

Comment: perfect, or should I say "dd647c3f2728e9355f760525508a50db" Thank you @lokheart

Answer (score 5):

`digest` as @lokheart pointed out is great.

another option is to simply use `factor`s.  `factor`s are numbers too. You get their numeric value by coercing via `as.numeric`.

```
 kvpairs <- factor(apply(X, 1, paste, collapse=""))
```

Now you have a pairing between the levels (the concat'd row strings) and the underlying numeric value.

```
# the numeric key of the first value
> as.numeric(kvpairs)[[1]]
[1] 2

# the value of key==2
> levels(kvpairs)[2]
[1] "1232012-11-18 50"


> kvpairs
[1] 1232012-11-18 50 1142012-05-07100
Levels: 1142012-05-07100 1232012-11-18 50
```

Note that if you add a duplicate row, it will have the same level (when concatenated).

Comment: Thanks @RicardoSaporta this would work too. Not sure if I would get the same factor value if the order of factors was different in a different data frame or if there were some factors absent from it.

Comment: @TahnoonPasha, if the order were different, yes, you would still get the same factors.  However, if values are missing then no, you would get different factors.

Answer (score 4):

Another option to create a unique key per row is to use `interaction`, for example :

```
 transform(dat,id =interaction(dat))

 id_1 id_2 id_3       date value                   id
1    1    2    3 2012-11-18    50  1.2.3.2012-11-18.50
2    1    1    4 2012-05-07   100 1.1.4.2012-05-07.100
```

**EDIT**

The default behvior is to retain all factor levels. It is better here to use `drop = TRUE` , so unused factor levels are dropped from the result.

```
  transform(dat,id =interaction(dat,drop=TRUE))

     id_1 id_2 id_3       date value                   id
    1    1    2    3 2012-11-18    50  1.2.3.2012-11-18.50
    2    1    1    4 2012-05-07   100 1.1.4.2012-05-07.100
```

Comment: I'm not sure how `interaction` here is being used differently from `apply(dat, 1, paste, collapse=".")`

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I am not sure if we can compare the 2 here? `interaction` computes a factor, `paste` just to create a string ( that you coerce it to a factor after). So I am confusing why this comment? to say that this solution is the same than yours maybe?:)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, that depends on what the OP wants to do. If for example he wants to get the sum of id_1 for *all possible combinations*, then `tapply(dat$id_1, dat$id, sum)` will give a different result than just `paste`. It may very well be the case that `interaction` is not necessary here. But it's just another way.

Comment: (+1). @agstudy, even then, it wont be the same. `interaction` gives all permutations. It's more like `do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(dat), sep=".")`. It wouldn't be wise to use it on a huge data.frame, I'd suppose as the permutations (for levels) would explode.

Comment: @Arun yes I agree. Maybe it is better here to set `drop=TRUE` , to drop unused factor levelse e.g: `intercation(...,drop=TRUE)`. But I think creating key is really interaction main job, not like `paste` where you do it "manually".

Comment: @agstudy, Yes indeed (forgot that parameter). I agree on both counts (drop=TRUE, `interaction` more appropriate).