# creating unique key using numbers from 1-10

Tags: r

I have to create different combination by selecting any 6 numbers(may change) out of 10 numbers(1-10)
I have got around 210 different combination .Now I want to create a unique key for each combination using the numbers within each combination.

```
       V1   V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8
        1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
        2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
        3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
        4   4   4   4   4   5   5   5
        5   6   7   8   9   6   7   8
Total   15  16  17  18  19  17  18  19
Key     --   -- --  --  --  --  --  --
```

I tried sum.. but sum is not coming unique..
I have also tried to convert numbers into binary and then take sum. but still no success
Please suggest some easy way to do this.

Comment: ...can you not just concatenate them? If they are unique combinations then concatenating them should yield a unique key.

Comment: The package `digest` is helpful for creating unique keys http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053337/r-create-a-unique-key-from-a-set-of-string-data

Comment: Numbers *are* binary. Even the binary representations (ASCII/Unicode values) of the *digit characters* are ordered. Summing them is no different than summing the numbers themselves in this respect

Comment: Just an aside, if you are choosing 6 distinguishable items from 10 such items without replacement, you shouldn't have "around" 210 combinations, but *exactly* 210 combinations :).

Comment: Hi Micah,Yes I can use the  Concatenation but the problem is ..I have another such tablle (old Table). I have to compare both tables and remove the columns from the new table which exactly matches with the old one. Here the order of the elements in the column doesn't matter. I have done this using for for loops but its becoming very slow .. as have to loop through each element. I thought of creating unique key for each column and so that I can avoid few loops.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask about the actual problem, not what's wrong with the attempted solution - you are trying to remove rows from one table that already exist in another. In other words, you want to find the [set difference](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html) between the new and old tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a unique key for each of the column using power of 2 (the base) corresponding to each elements and sum together.

so for V1 the total is 2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4=30. As  all the columns are unique (unique combination), this key is unique. So i created two vectors of sum for new and old data.
Old data Vector
V1  V2  V3...
126 196 318..

new Data Vector
V1  V2  V3...
130 196 350..

Now comparing the new data vector using loops

```
for (i in length(new_listn):1){
           if ((match(new_listn[i], old_list, nomatch = 0))>0){
           comps_comb<-comps_comb[-(i)]
                      }
```

here i represents the column in the vector and corresponding data frame Comp_comb
Basically if the key from new data  is matching with any key in the old data corresponding column is removed..
It works perfectly fine..

Thanks to you all for suggesting solution. I really love this group..
......

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it appears the *real* problem is that you have two tables and want to find and remove from table A the rows that exactly match any rows in table B. In other words, you want to find the set difference between A and B.

One way to do it is by using the [setdiff](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html) function. `setdiff` converts everything to a vector, so we need to convert the input matrices to list of columns first.

```
x<-combn(10,6)
y<-combn(11,6)

## Create a list of columns to use with setdiff
xCols<-lapply(seq_len(ncol(x)), function(i) x[,i])
yCols<-lapply(seq_len(ncol(y)), function(i) y[,i])

## Get the columns from y that aren't in x
diffCols<-setdiff(yCols,xCols)

## Convert back to matrix
matrix(unlist(diffCols),nrow=6)

         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] ...
    [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
    [2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
    [3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3
    [4,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    5    5    5
    [5,]    5    6    7    8    9   10    6    7    8
    [6,]   11   11   11   11   11   11   11   11   11
```

Another option, similar to what you tried to do, is to find the difference between the concatenated values. This isn't faster though, as comparing the concatenated string isn't faster than comparing the original values - the comparison must be done one character at a time:

```
## Calculate a key for each column
xCols<-sapply(seq_len(ncol(x)), function(i) paste(x[,i],collapse="-"))
yCols<-sapply(seq_len(ncol(y)), function(i) paste(y[,i],collapse="-"))

## Return only columns that don't have a match
y[,which(match(yCols,xCols,0L)==0,arr.ind=TRUE)]
```